# Android - How to add animation (Zoom in) only to background image without affecting others?

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

I'm thinking of making an app's first view like this: it's just a basic search view with one `EditText` and two `Button` on it. I want the background image zooming in and out when user stay on this view, typing or doing nothing.

So I add zoomin.xml and set the animation to the view. Zooming is working but only problem is that it's zooming everything. I know it's because I set background image in the root element of the xml, but I don't know how to make it ONLY zoom in the background picture without affecting other views.

Here's my background image code in root element.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/bcg2"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">
```

So I'm thinking if any floating view will do this? But I don't know how to do it. Or any other suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: can u  share how u done ? i also want to zoomout apply on button while button contains backgrind image and text my code is zooming out only text not background image how to resolve?

Answer (score 2):

Use a fullscrean ImageView instead of the background attribute of the Linearlayout and zoom only the image

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_to_zoom"
        android:src="@drawable/bcg2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The animation works! But there's still some white border left, the background image is not full filled into background. I tried some other ways and other images still shows white border. Do you know why?

Comment: Ok I fix this by zoom in the image from 120% to 450% instead of from 100% to 450% so the image will not show white border in the beginning. I don't know how to remove the border, this seems work fine though.

Comment: Set scaleType in ImageView like this:
android:scaleType="centerCrop"